# Obj.Constructor function property using this returns as the function property rather than the Object

Tags: javascript, constructor, modular

So I am trying to make a modular system that so far is working besides getting a variable/object property this is what I am doing

```
var obj1 = function(){
   this.objList = [];
   var obj2 = function(){
     this.var = 0;
   }

   this.createObj = function(){
       var ent = new obj2();
       //newId would change with a for loop counter too lazy to write it
       this.objList[newId] = ent;
   }

   this.newFuncProp = function(){
      console(this.var);
   }
}
var objClass = new obj1();
objClass.createObj();
objClass.objList[newId].constructor.prop = objClass.newFuncProp;
objClass.objList[newId].prop();
```

The call at the end of the code would log to the console NaN and if I logged this instead it would log that function only. How do I properly access this.var?

Comment: You're missing `var obj = new obj1()`.  Then, call methods on `obj` like `obj.createObj()`.  `createObj` is not a method of `obj1`.  It's a method of an instance of `obj1`.  Or assign `obj1.createObj = function() {...}` to put `createObj` as a propery of `obj1`.

Comment: jFriend in my actual code I initilized the object properly I will update my code here to reflect that sorry.

Comment: As written, objList is not a property of the objClass instance, it is a variable. You won't be able to access it like this: objClass.objList. If you want it to be an accessible property, in the constructor, write it: `this.objList = []`

Comment: Yes however this is not the problem I am having however I will fix it again,

Comment: Also as a backstory for this Pseudo code I am writing my own game engine, and I am trying to add a Rigidbody property to an entity which I have a entities class with a superclass of entity, entities stores properties that can be prototyped onto actual entities I.E the entity superclass, in which a new entity is created by calling for one to be created in the regular class. However this seems impossible to do if I cannot access the constructor obj and this is actually the property instead of the actual object.

Comment: Did you mean `objClass.objList[newId].constructor.prototype.prop = objClass.newFuncProp;`? Assigning `.prop` on `obj2` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Whatever you are doing, it is generally a very very bad idea to nest classes within each other in JS. Rather make two separate classes and pass an instance of one to the constructor of the other.

Comment: Bergi, I tried that just now, and it didn't really change anything, and it didn't fix the problem, but it did allow me to get that function from the object directly.

Comment: Well there are a number of odd things here, but if all you want is to access `this.var` on obj2 instances, and you know the id in the objList, you can access it directly: `objClass.objList[newId].var`

Comment: if I could directly know the id I wouldn't be using a this.property I would use a variable and a return function